# Is there a way to caculate the width and height of jpeg

Tags: c#, matlab, exif, libjpeg

I have some corrupted JPEG patched with good header from same chorma sampling 4:2:2

But i have issue with demension of jpeg from the good header to corrupt data

How can i automate calculator the width and height of raw data to this header to make image have good view of demension?

My jpeg preview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJaeo.jpg

The jpeg file:

(https://www.mediafire.com/file/hnmfutz3p7kbx2s/_NHL0591_.JPG/file)

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a JPEG where the header was damaged, and you're trying to rebuild it?

Comment: Yes, the corrupted jpeg 153605 bytes from the header ( no SOI -> SOS ) so i cut it and get raw data merger to a standard tables huffman code and dqt tables jpeg sample but the width and height came with the sample jpeg, i'm trying to rebuild jpeg structure

Comment: I'm not convinced that's possible.  You can see that the scanlines are about 3.8 times as wide as you have it, which suggests that it's a 4K image (3840x2160).

Comment: When i change follow your demension jpeg look like this: https://www.mediafire.com/file/moaqsw76pc64dz7/63665707-7780-454B-81B8-33BE2D16C4E9.png/file